# Testing binary search module, based on bisect

Tags: python, unit-testing, binary-search

The bisect module can only find the index to insert an element. I created a simple class based on the bisect module for precise searching and covered all the edge cases that came to mind with tests.
Could you please check the correctness of the tests for the binary search extension module? I want to make sure that the tests match the function documentation ([docstrings](https://peps.python.org/pep-0257/)). Well, maybe more you could review the code, or suggest optimizations?

---

My code:

```
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right

class BisectFinder:
    ''' This class contains some convenient binary search functions for an element in a list '''
        
    @staticmethod
    def find_left_lt(a, x, lo=0, hi=None, key=None):
        '''Finds the index of the leftmost (among duplicates) element that is strictly less than X.
        
        A[index] < X
        
        A[index] == a2
        
        [
            a1{<x}, a1{<x}, A[index], a2{<x}, a2{<x},
            
            a3{<=x}, a3{<=x}, a4{<=x}, a4{<=x},
            
            a5{==x}, a5{==x},
            
            a7{>=x}, a7{>=x}, a8{>=x}, a8{>=x},
            
            a9{>x}, a9{>x}, a10{>x}, a10{>x}
        ]
        '''
        
        index = bisect_left(a, x, lo=lo, hi=hi, key=key)
        if len(a) > 0 and index < len(a) + 1 and a[index - 1] < x:
            return bisect_left(a, a[index - 1], lo=lo, hi=index-1, key=key)
        
        raise ValueError("No elements less than x found.")

    @staticmethod
    def find_left_le(a, x, lo=0, hi=None, key=None):
        '''Finds the index of the leftmost (among duplicates) element that is less than or equal to X.
        
        A[index] <= X
        
        A[index] == a4
        
        [
            a1{<x}, a1{<x}, a2{<x}, a2{<x},
            
            a3{<=x}, a3{<=x}, A[index], a4{<=x}, a4{<=x},
            
            a5{==x}, a5{==x},
            
            a7{>=x}, a7{>=x}, a8{>=x}, a8{>=x},
            
            a9{>x}, a9{>x}, a10{>x}, a10{>x}
        ]
        '''
        
        index = bisect_right(a, x, lo=lo, hi=hi, key=key)
        if len(a) > 0 and index < len(a) + 1 and a[index - 1] <= x:
            return bisect_left(a, a[index - 1], lo=lo, hi=index-1, key=key)
        
        raise ValueError("No elements less than or equal to x found.")

    @staticmethod
    def find_left_eq(a, x, lo=0, hi=None, key=None):
        '''Finds the index of the leftmost (among duplicates) element that is equal to X.
        
        A[index] == X
        
        A[index] == a5
        
        [
            a1{<x}, a1{<x}, a2{<x}, a2{<x},
            
            a3{<=x}, a3{<=x}, a4{<=x}, a4{<=x},
            
            A[index], a5{==x}, a5{==x},
            
            a7{>=x}, a7{>=x}, a8{>=x}, a8{>=x},
            
            a9{>x}, a9{>x}, a10{>x}, a10{>x}
        ]
        '''
        
        index = bisect_left(a, x, lo=lo, hi=hi, key=key)
        if index != len(a) and a[index] == x:
            return index
        
        raise ValueError("No elements equal to x found.")

    @staticmethod
    def find_left_ge(a, x, lo=0, hi=None, key=None):
        '''Finds the index of the leftmost (among duplicates) element that is greater than or equal to X.
        
        A[index] >= X
        
        A[index] == a7
        
        [
            a1{<x}, a1{<x}, a2{<x}, a2{<x},
            
            a3{<=x}, a3{<=x}, a4{<=x}, a4{<=x},
            
            a5{==x}, a5{==x},
            
            A[index], a7{>=x}, a7{>=x}, a8{>=x}, a8{>=x},
            
            a9{>x}, a9{>x}, a10{>x}, a10{>x}
        ]
        '''
        
        index = bisect_left(a, x, lo=lo, hi=hi, key=key)
        if index != len(a):
            return index
        
        raise ValueError("No elements greater than or equal to x found.")

    @staticmethod
    def find_left_gt(a, x, lo=0, hi=None, key=None):
        '''Finds the index of the leftmost (among duplicates) element that is strictly greater than X.
        
        A[index] > X
        
        A[index] == a9
        
        [
            a1{<x}, a1{<x}, a2{<x}, a2{<x},
            
            a3{<=x}, a3{<=x}, a4{<=x}, a4{<=x},
            
            a5{==x}, a5{==x},
            
            a7{>=x}, a7{>=x}, a8{>=x}, a8{>=x},
            
            A[index], a9{>x}, a9{>x}, a10{>x}, a10{>x}
        ]
        '''
        
        index = bisect_right(a, x, lo=lo, hi=hi, key=key)
        if index != len(a):
            return index
        
        raise ValueError("No elements greater than x found.")

    @staticmethod
    def find_right_lt(a, x, lo=0, hi=None, key=None):
        '''Finds the index of the rightmost (among duplicates) element that is strictly less than X.
        
        A[index] < X
        
        A[index] == a2
        
        [
            a1{<x}, a1{<x}, a2{<x}, a2{<x}, A[index],
            
            a3{<=x}, a3{<=x}, a4{<=x}, a4{<=x},
            
            a5{==x}, a5{==x},
            
            a7{>=x}, a7{>=x}, a8{>=x}, a8{>=x},
            
            a9{>x}, a9{>x}, a10{>x}, a10{>x}
        ]
        '''
        
        index = bisect_left(a, x, lo=lo, hi=hi, key=key)
        if index:
            return index-1
        
        raise ValueError("No elements less than x found.")

    @staticmethod
    def find_right_le(a, x, lo=0, hi=None, key=None):
        '''Finds the index of the rightmost (among duplicates) element that is less than or equal to X.
        
        A[index] <= X
        
        A[index] == a4
        
        [
            a1{<x}, a1{<x}, a2{<x}, a2{<x},
            
            a3{<=x}, a3{<=x}, a4{<=x}, a4{<=x}, A[index],
            
            a5{==x}, a5{==x},
            
            a7{>=x}, a7{>=x}, a8{>=x}, a8{>=x},
            
            a9{>x}, a9{>x}, a10{>x}, a10{>x}
        ]
        '''
        
        index = bisect_right(a, x, lo=lo, hi=hi, key=key)
        if index:
            return index-1
        
        raise ValueError("No elements less than or equal to x found.")

    @staticmethod
    def find_right_eq(a, x, lo=0, hi=None, key=None):
        '''Finds the index of the rightmost (among duplicates) element that is equal to X.
        
        A[index] == X
        
        A[index] == a5
        
        [
            a1{<x}, a1{<x}, a2{<x}, a2{<x},
            
            a3{<=x}, a3{<=x}, a4{<=x}, a4{<=x},
            
            a5{==x}, a5{==x}, A[index],
            
            a7{>=x}, a7{>=x}, a8{>=x}, a8{>=x},
            
            a9{>x}, a9{>x}, a10{>x}, a10{>x}
        ]
        '''
        
        index = bisect_left(a, x, lo=lo, hi=hi, key=key)
        if index != len(a) and a[index] == x:
            return bisect_right(a, a[index], lo=index, hi=hi, key=key) - 1
        
        raise ValueError("No elements equal to x found.")

    @staticmethod
    def find_right_ge(a, x, lo=0, hi=None, key=None):
        '''Finds the index of the rightmost (among duplicates) element that is greater than or equal to X.
        
        A[index] >= X
        
        A[index] == a7
        
        [
            a1{<x}, a1{<x}, a2{<x}, a2{<x},
            
            a3{<=x}, a3{<=x}, a4{<=x}, a4{<=x},
            
            a5{==x}, a5{==x},
            
            a7{>=x}, a7{>=x}, A[index], a8{>=x}, a8{>=x},
            
            a9{>x}, a9{>x}, a10{>x}, a10{>x}
        ]
        '''
        
        index = bisect_left(a, x, lo=lo, hi=hi, key=key)
        if index != len(a):
            return bisect_right(a, a[index], lo=index, hi=hi, key=key) - 1
        
        raise ValueError("No elements greater than or equal to x found.")

    @staticmethod
    def find_right_gt(a, x, lo=0, hi=None, key=None):
        '''Finds the index of the rightmost (among duplicates) element that is strictly greater than X.
        
        A[index] > X
        
        A[index] == a9
        
        [
            a1{<x}, a1{<x}, a2{<x}, a2{<x},
            
            a3{<=x}, a3{<=x}, a4{<=x}, a4{<=x},
            
            a5{==x}, a5{==x},
            
            a7{>=x}, a7{>=x}, a8{>=x}, a8{>=x},
            
            a9{>x}, a9{>x}, A[index], a10{>x}, a10{>x}
        ]
        '''
        
        index = bisect_right(a, x, lo=lo, hi=hi, key=key)
        if index != len(a):
            return bisect_right(a, a[index], lo=index, hi=hi, key=key) - 1

        raise ValueError("No elements greater than x found.")
```

My tests:

```
import unittest
from unittest import TestCase
from implements import BisectFinder

class TestBisectFinder(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.empty_list = []                        # 10
        self.one_element_list = [5]                 # 2, 5, 7
        self.two_element_list = [3, 8]              # 2, 3, 6, 8, 9
        self.three_element_list = [2, 7, 7]         # 1, 2, 4, 7, 8
        self.four_element_list = [2, 2, 2, 5]       # 1, 2, 4, 5, 6
        self.five_element_list = [1, 5, 5, 5, 9]    # 0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 9, 10


    # Tests for the find_left_lt function

    def test_find_left_lt_empty_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_lt, self.empty_list, 10)

    def test_find_left_lt_one_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_lt, self.one_element_list, 2)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_lt, self.one_element_list, 5)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_lt(self.one_element_list, 7), 0)

    def test_find_left_lt_two_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_lt, self.two_element_list, 2)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_lt, self.two_element_list, 3)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_lt(self.two_element_list, 6), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_lt(self.two_element_list, 8), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_lt(self.two_element_list, 9), 1)
        
    def test_find_left_lt_three_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_lt, self.three_element_list, 1)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_lt, self.three_element_list, 2)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_lt(self.three_element_list, 4), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_lt(self.three_element_list, 7), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_lt(self.three_element_list, 8), 1)
        
    def test_find_left_lt_four_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_lt, self.four_element_list, 1)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_lt, self.four_element_list, 2)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_lt(self.four_element_list, 4), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_lt(self.four_element_list, 5), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_lt(self.four_element_list, 6), 3)

    def test_find_left_lt_five_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_lt, self.five_element_list, 0)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_lt, self.five_element_list, 1)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_lt(self.five_element_list, 2), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_lt(self.five_element_list, 5), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_lt(self.five_element_list, 7), 1)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_lt(self.five_element_list, 9), 1)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_lt(self.five_element_list, 10), 4)


    # Tests for the find_left_le function

    def test_find_left_le_empty_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_le, self.empty_list, 10)

    def test_find_left_le_one_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_le, self.one_element_list, 2)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_le(self.one_element_list, 5), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_le(self.one_element_list, 7), 0)

    def test_find_left_le_two_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_le, self.two_element_list, 2)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_le(self.two_element_list, 3), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_le(self.two_element_list, 6), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_le(self.two_element_list, 8), 1)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_le(self.two_element_list, 9), 1)
        
    def test_find_left_le_three_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_le, self.three_element_list, 1)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_le(self.three_element_list, 2), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_le(self.three_element_list, 4), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_le(self.three_element_list, 7), 1)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_le(self.three_element_list, 8), 1)
        
    def test_find_left_le_four_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_le, self.four_element_list, 1)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_le(self.four_element_list, 2), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_le(self.four_element_list, 4), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_le(self.four_element_list, 5), 3)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_le(self.four_element_list, 6), 3)

    def test_find_left_le_five_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_le, self.five_element_list, 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_le(self.five_element_list, 1), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_le(self.five_element_list, 2), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_le(self.five_element_list, 5), 1)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_le(self.five_element_list, 7), 1)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_le(self.five_element_list, 9), 4)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_le(self.five_element_list, 10), 4)


    # Tests for the find_left_eq function

    def test_find_left_eq_empty_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_eq, self.empty_list, 10)

    def test_find_left_eq_one_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_eq, self.one_element_list, 2)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_eq(self.one_element_list, 5), 0)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_eq, self.one_element_list, 7)

    def test_find_left_eq_two_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_eq, self.two_element_list, 2)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_eq(self.two_element_list, 3), 0)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_eq, self.two_element_list, 6)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_eq(self.two_element_list, 8), 1)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_eq, self.two_element_list, 9)
        
    def test_find_left_eq_three_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_eq, self.three_element_list, 1)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_eq(self.three_element_list, 2), 0)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_eq, self.three_element_list, 4)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_eq(self.three_element_list, 7), 1)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_eq, self.three_element_list, 8)
        
    def test_find_left_eq_four_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_eq, self.four_element_list, 1)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_eq(self.four_element_list, 2), 0)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_eq, self.four_element_list, 4)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_eq(self.four_element_list, 5), 3)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_eq, self.four_element_list, 6)

    def test_find_left_eq_five_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_eq, self.five_element_list, 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_eq(self.five_element_list, 1), 0)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_eq, self.five_element_list, 2)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_eq(self.five_element_list, 5), 1)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_eq, self.five_element_list, 7)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_eq(self.five_element_list, 9), 4)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_eq, self.five_element_list, 10)


    # Tests for the find_left_ge function

    def test_find_left_ge_empty_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_ge, self.empty_list, 10)

    def test_find_left_ge_one_element_list(self):
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_ge(self.one_element_list, 2), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_ge(self.one_element_list, 5), 0)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_ge, self.one_element_list, 7)

    def test_find_left_ge_two_element_list(self):
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_ge(self.two_element_list, 2), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_ge(self.two_element_list, 3), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_ge(self.two_element_list, 6), 1)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_ge(self.two_element_list, 8), 1)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_ge, self.two_element_list, 9)

    def test_find_left_ge_three_element_list(self):
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_ge(self.three_element_list, 1), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_ge(self.three_element_list, 2), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_ge(self.three_element_list, 4), 1)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_ge(self.three_element_list, 7), 1)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_ge, self.three_element_list, 8)
        
    def test_find_left_ge_four_element_list(self):
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_ge(self.four_element_list, 1), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_ge(self.four_element_list, 2), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_ge(self.four_element_list, 4), 3)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_ge(self.four_element_list, 5), 3)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_ge, self.four_element_list, 6)
        
    def test_find_left_ge_five_element_list(self):
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_ge(self.five_element_list, 0), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_ge(self.five_element_list, 1), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_ge(self.five_element_list, 2), 1)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_ge(self.five_element_list, 5), 1)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_ge(self.five_element_list, 7), 4)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_ge(self.five_element_list, 9), 4)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_ge, self.five_element_list, 10)


    # Tests for the find_left_gt function

    def test_find_left_gt_empty_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_gt, self.empty_list, 10)

    def test_find_left_gt_one_element_list(self):
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_gt(self.one_element_list, 2), 0)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_gt, self.one_element_list, 5)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_gt, self.one_element_list, 7)

    def test_find_left_gt_two_element_list(self):
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_gt(self.two_element_list, 2), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_gt(self.two_element_list, 3), 1)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_gt(self.two_element_list, 6), 1)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_gt, self.two_element_list, 8)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_gt, self.two_element_list, 9)

    def test_find_left_gt_three_element_list(self):
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_gt(self.three_element_list, 1), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_gt(self.three_element_list, 2), 1)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_gt(self.three_element_list, 4), 1)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_gt, self.three_element_list, 7)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_gt, self.three_element_list, 8)
        
    def test_find_left_gt_four_element_list(self):
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_gt(self.four_element_list, 1), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_gt(self.four_element_list, 2), 3)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_gt(self.four_element_list, 4), 3)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_gt, self.four_element_list, 5)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_gt, self.four_element_list, 6)
    
    def test_find_left_gt_five_element_list(self):
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_gt(self.five_element_list, 0), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_gt(self.five_element_list, 1), 1)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_gt(self.five_element_list, 2), 1)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_gt(self.five_element_list, 5), 4)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_left_gt(self.five_element_list, 7), 4)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_gt, self.five_element_list, 9)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_left_gt, self.five_element_list, 10)


    # Tests for the find_right_lt function

    def test_find_right_lt_empty_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_lt, self.empty_list, 10)

    def test_find_right_lt_one_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_lt, self.one_element_list, 2)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_lt, self.one_element_list, 5)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_lt(self.one_element_list, 7), 0)

    def test_find_right_lt_two_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_lt, self.two_element_list, 2)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_lt, self.two_element_list, 3)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_lt(self.two_element_list, 6), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_lt(self.two_element_list, 8), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_lt(self.two_element_list, 9), 1)
        
    def test_find_right_lt_three_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_lt, self.three_element_list, 1)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_lt, self.three_element_list, 2)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_lt(self.three_element_list, 4), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_lt(self.three_element_list, 7), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_lt(self.three_element_list, 8), 2)
        
    def test_find_right_lt_four_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_lt, self.four_element_list, 1)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_lt, self.four_element_list, 2)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_lt(self.four_element_list, 4), 2)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_lt(self.four_element_list, 5), 2)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_lt(self.four_element_list, 6), 3)

    def test_find_right_lt_five_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_lt, self.five_element_list, 0)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_lt, self.five_element_list, 1)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_lt(self.five_element_list, 2), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_lt(self.five_element_list, 5), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_lt(self.five_element_list, 7), 3)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_lt(self.five_element_list, 9), 3)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_lt(self.five_element_list, 10), 4)


    # Tests for the find_right_le function

    def test_find_right_le_empty_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_le, self.empty_list, 10)

    def test_find_right_le_one_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_le, self.one_element_list, 2)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_le(self.one_element_list, 5), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_le(self.one_element_list, 7), 0)

    def test_find_right_le_two_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_le, self.two_element_list, 2)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_le(self.two_element_list, 3), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_le(self.two_element_list, 6), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_le(self.two_element_list, 8), 1)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_le(self.two_element_list, 9), 1)
        
    def test_find_right_le_three_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_le, self.three_element_list, 1)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_le(self.three_element_list, 2), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_le(self.three_element_list, 4), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_le(self.three_element_list, 7), 2)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_le(self.three_element_list, 8), 2)
        
    def test_find_right_le_four_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_le, self.four_element_list, 1)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_le(self.four_element_list, 2), 2)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_le(self.four_element_list, 4), 2)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_le(self.four_element_list, 5), 3)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_le(self.four_element_list, 6), 3)

    def test_find_right_le_five_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_le, self.five_element_list, 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_le(self.five_element_list, 1), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_le(self.five_element_list, 2), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_le(self.five_element_list, 5), 3)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_le(self.five_element_list, 7), 3)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_le(self.five_element_list, 9), 4)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_le(self.five_element_list, 10), 4)


    # Tests for the find_right_eq function

    def test_find_right_eq_empty_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_eq, self.empty_list, 10)

    def test_find_right_eq_one_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_eq, self.one_element_list, 2)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_eq(self.one_element_list, 5), 0)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_eq, self.one_element_list, 7)

    def test_find_right_eq_two_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_eq, self.two_element_list, 2)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_eq(self.two_element_list, 3), 0)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_eq, self.two_element_list, 6)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_eq(self.two_element_list, 8), 1)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_eq, self.two_element_list, 9)
        
    def test_find_right_eq_three_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_eq, self.three_element_list, 1)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_eq(self.three_element_list, 2), 0)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_eq, self.three_element_list, 4)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_eq(self.three_element_list, 7), 2)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_eq, self.three_element_list, 8)
        
    def test_find_right_eq_four_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_eq, self.four_element_list, 1)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_eq(self.four_element_list, 2), 2)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_eq, self.four_element_list, 4)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_eq(self.four_element_list, 5), 3)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_eq, self.four_element_list, 6)

    def test_find_right_eq_five_element_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_eq, self.five_element_list, 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_eq(self.five_element_list, 1), 0)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_eq, self.five_element_list, 2)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_eq(self.five_element_list, 5), 3)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_eq, self.five_element_list, 7)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_eq(self.five_element_list, 9), 4)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_eq, self.five_element_list, 10)


    # Tests for the find_right_ge function

    def test_find_right_ge_empty_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_ge, self.empty_list, 10)

    def test_find_right_ge_one_element_list(self):
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_ge(self.one_element_list, 2), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_ge(self.one_element_list, 5), 0)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_ge, self.one_element_list, 7)

    def test_find_right_ge_two_element_list(self):
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_ge(self.two_element_list, 2), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_ge(self.two_element_list, 3), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_ge(self.two_element_list, 6), 1)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_ge(self.two_element_list, 8), 1)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_ge, self.two_element_list, 9)

    def test_find_right_ge_three_element_list(self):
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_ge(self.three_element_list, 1), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_ge(self.three_element_list, 2), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_ge(self.three_element_list, 4), 2)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_ge(self.three_element_list, 7), 2)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_ge, self.three_element_list, 8)
        
    def test_find_right_ge_four_element_list(self):
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_ge(self.four_element_list, 1), 2)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_ge(self.four_element_list, 2), 2)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_ge(self.four_element_list, 4), 3)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_ge(self.four_element_list, 5), 3)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_ge, self.four_element_list, 6)

    def test_find_right_ge_five_element_list(self):
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_ge(self.five_element_list, 0), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_ge(self.five_element_list, 1), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_ge(self.five_element_list, 2), 3)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_ge(self.five_element_list, 5), 3)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_ge(self.five_element_list, 7), 4)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_ge(self.five_element_list, 9), 4)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_ge, self.five_element_list, 10)


    # Tests for the find_right_gt function

    def test_find_right_gt_empty_list(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_gt, self.empty_list, 10)

    def test_find_right_gt_one_element_list(self):
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_gt(self.one_element_list, 2), 0)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_gt, self.one_element_list, 5)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_gt, self.one_element_list, 7)

    def test_find_right_gt_two_element_list(self):
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_gt(self.two_element_list, 2), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_gt(self.two_element_list, 3), 1)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_gt(self.two_element_list, 6), 1)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_gt, self.two_element_list, 8)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_gt, self.two_element_list, 9)

    def test_find_right_gt_three_element_list(self):
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_gt(self.three_element_list, 1), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_gt(self.three_element_list, 2), 2)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_gt(self.three_element_list, 4), 2)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_gt, self.three_element_list, 7)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_gt, self.three_element_list, 8)
        
    def test_find_right_gt_four_element_list(self):
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_gt(self.four_element_list, 1), 2)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_gt(self.four_element_list, 2), 3)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_gt(self.four_element_list, 4), 3)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_gt, self.four_element_list, 5)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_gt, self.four_element_list, 6)

    def test_find_right_gt_five_element_list(self):
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_gt(self.five_element_list, 0), 0)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_gt(self.five_element_list, 1), 3)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_gt(self.five_element_list, 2), 3)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_gt(self.five_element_list, 5), 4)
        self.assertEqual(BisectFinder.find_right_gt(self.five_element_list, 7), 4)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_gt, self.five_element_list, 9)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, BisectFinder.find_right_gt, self.five_element_list, 10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: *"Finds the index of the leftmost (among duplicates) element that is strictly less than X"* - Uh... Isn't that simply the index 0? Unless that already contains an element not strictly less than X, in which case what should happen?

Comment: @KellyBundy thanks for the note. "leftmost (among duplicates)" only. 'find_left_le([1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5], 4) == 2'

Comment: So `find_left_le([1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5], 4) == 0`? Because here, `1` is a duplicate.

Comment: @KellyBundy Hmm... I think I understand what I did wrong... But this is a documentation problem. The tests in this case do what I would like to see in functions. I want to find the "closest" (that is, the rightmost one, for the functions `lt`, `le`, the leftmost one for `ge`, `gt`) and, if there are several answers, then find the leftmost one. This is true for all `left_...` functions.

Comment: Yes, I do think there's a "rightmost" or "largest" or so missing.

Comment: @KellyBundy yep. I add them to new version of my module.

Comment: Btw did you see [these](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#searching-sorted-lists)? Looks like you replicated some of them.

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes, that was intentional. I started with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## testing approach

```
from unittest import TestCase
```

Good!

You may wish to consider using
[hypothesis](https://pypi.org/project/hypothesis),
as well. It does an amazing job of thinking up
random test cases that you never would have,
and then tries to distill them down to
"simplest input which still produces Red bar".

BTW, `implements` seems an odd module name,
which the Review Context never mentions.

## AAA

The "arrange" part has been moved out to `setUp`,
and the tests focus on "act, assert".

This *can* be good, if arranging is "hard" or tediously long,
and *especially* if we arrange a common data structure
which is used by multiple independent tests.

But here the separation is slightly distracting.
I have a weak preference for seeing the one-line "arrange"
setting a local variable which we use on the next line.

## edge cases

I will focus on just one test; others follow a similar pattern.

In `test_find_left_lt_one_element_list` the element to be
found is `5`, and we systematically test {`2`, `5`, `7`}.
I would rather have seen {`4`, `5`, `6`} being tested.
When we wrote the target code we *tried* to correctly
use `<` vs `<=` operators.
The point of test code is to *verify* the right thing happened.

## verbose tests

Oh my goodness, the tests just go on,
cycling through {left, right} × {`<`, `<=`, `==`, `>=`, `>`}.
Humans aren't great at going through such enumerations.
My eyes glaze over.

OK, you win, I guess factoring out all the "arrange" into `setUp`
*was* the right call, for these particular tests.

Yes, test code should be "very simple", and
we embrace copy-n-paste for it.
But after ten stanzas, I'm not sure these are exactly "simple",
in the sense that I'm not doing a good job of eye-balling
each one and deciding "oh yeah, *this* is the right answer"
before reading what the assertion says.

Instead of these, or in addition to these,
I would like to see some test logic that constructs a list
so it knows the right answer, then verifies that the right
answer is returned.
It would accept `list_length` as a parameter.

And then add some
[hypothesis](https://pypi.org/project/hypothesis)
testing on top of that.

I'm starting to wish there was a (possibly `_private`) method
that accepts a comparison operator.
It would simplify cycling through the variants.

## @staticmethod

There's nothing exactly *wrong* with using that decorator.
But introducing a "container" class to organize the namespace
is unnecessary, a module can certainly do that.

Consider using simple `def`s in a `bisectfinder` module.

## signature

```
    def find_left_lt(a, x, lo=0, hi=None, key=None):
```

Leaving `a` and `x` as type `Any` is fine,
and caller will soon figure out that the `Sequence` `a`
should contain elements of `x`'s type,
and the elements should support comparison.

Neglecting to point out that we return `def ... ) -> int:`
seems like a missed opportunity.
Plus, it makes `mypy` linting slightly harder for callers.

## docstring

```
        '''Finds the index of the leftmost (among duplicates) element that is strictly less than X.
        
        A[index] < X
        
        A[index] == a2
```

I appreciate the pithiness of that sentence.

The `< X` postcondition could clarify that it's a contract,
it *shall* be true upon return.
The notation upcases `a` and `x` where that doesn't seem necessary.
I don't know where `a2` came from,
and if the intent is to promise some postcondition,
I'm afraid I'm not quite getting it.
The `[` list `]` which follows I found entirely obscure.

I was a little surprised to see no mention of the familiar
[bisect_left](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left),
for example to contrast their behavior.
Plus, the meaning of `key` here matches its behavior in every way.

That familiar function is a
[total](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function)
function.
The docstring makes no mention that `find_left_lt`
is a partial function which could very well `raise`.
This is a serious omission and should be remedied.

## custom exception

I'm not entirely comfortable with using `ValueError` for failures.
It feels more like an `IndexError` happened -- "bad index",
no matching index exists.

Consider defining your own exception,
and have it inherit from `IndexError`.
Then a caller a few levels up the call stack
can focus on your specific exception if desired,
or can choose to catch just `IndexError` or `Exception`
if that's sufficient for caller's need.

```
        raise ValueError("No elements less than or equal to x found.")
```

This is less informative than it could be.
Put yourself in the shoes of some maintenance engineer who is staring at this message.
First question is going to be "what was `x`?", right?
Consider using an f-string to put the value of `x` in there.

<del>I find it interesting that only the message changes
between e.g. `find_right_ge` and `find_right_gt`.</del>

Perhaps the message template
might become a keyword parameter.

## simple comparisons

```
        if len(a) > 0 and index < len(a) + 1 and a[index - 1] < x:
```

I find those three conjuncts harder to read than necessary.
And I believe you do, too.

Let's tackle the middle one.
It's a guard, but it's more obscure than needed.
It could be:

```
        if    ...     and index - 1 < len(a)  and  a[index - 1] < x:
```

which makes it transparently obvious that we're avoiding
running off the end.

But `bisect_left()` is perfectly happy to return an index of `0`.
Don't we want to verify that `index - 1` hasn't walked
off the *other* end of the array?!?

I confess it is not completely clear to me how `lo` and `hi`
figure into this.
The test suite did not consider them, but it should.

The underlying `bisect_left` uses `lo` and `hi`,
so there's a good case for keeping them as-is.
Let me float a radical proposal.
Consider accepting a single `range` argument,
and then you pass `.start` and `.stop` to `bisect_left`.
Or not, whatever.
It slightly simplifies the promises
and is perhaps a little easier to reason about
in the presence of potential
[OBOBs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).

## postcondition

I really liked how the one sentence ("Finds the index...") states a
[contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract).
I would like it even more if it was believable,
if I *knew* for certain it was always true after my call.
There's an easy way to do that: use `assert` before returning.

Comment: Pardon, I stand corrected. (I was also trying to see where passing in a function that defaults to `bisect_left` could be fruitfully applied, should have looked there!) Reducing the `[` ... `]` verbiage in function docstrings would make it easier to scroll around and compare those functions. Generally I felt it should have been easier to compare and contrast those related functions, given that there's only a few SLOC. That's the effect that DRYing things up by parameterizing tends to have.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I will take into account all or almost all of this.